# Collection object in Discord.js emptying after being successfully set

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

So I am running into an issue with my collections object in the Discord.js library. I am working on a command and event handler to populate a collection of commands and events based on the files written in each directory. Each collection appears to populate properly as long as I check it within the map function. Immediately after the second map is complete, whichever collection I populate second becomes empty, yet the first collection remains set.

If I reverse the order they are set, the problem changes to whichever collection is set second. And because they both set fine when debugged within the map or if they are set first, I am confident it is not related to anything directory wise or with the files they are importing. I suspect it is somehow related to how collections work on an object that I am unaware of.

Any insight to this would be great!

```
import { Command, Event, Config } from "../Interfaces/index"
import { Client, Collection, Intents } from "discord.js"
import glob from "glob";
import { promisify } from "util";

const globPromise = promisify(glob)

class Bot extends Client {
  public events: Collection<string, Event> = new Collection()
  public commands: Collection<string, Command> = new Collection()
  public aliases: Collection<string, Command> = new Collection()
  public config: Config

  public constructor() {
    super({ ws: { intents: Intents.ALL } })
  }

  public async init(config: Config): Promise<void> {
    this.config = config
    this.login(this.config.token)

    const commandFiles: string[] = await globPromise(`${__dirname}/../Commands/**/*.ts`)
    commandFiles.map(async (filePath: string) => {
      const { command }: { command: Command } = await import(filePath)
      this.commands.set(command.name, command)
      if (command.aliases?.length !== 0) {
        command.aliases?.forEach((alias) => {
          this.aliases.set(alias, command)
        })
      }
    })

    const eventfiles: string[] = await globPromise(`${__dirname}/../Events/**/*.ts`)
    eventfiles.map(async (filePath: string) => {
      const { event }: { event: Event } = await import(filePath)
      this.events.set(event.name, event)
      console.log(this) // Events and commands collection are populated
    })
      console.log(this) // Events collection is empty and commands collection is populated
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not know, but you mapped each of the `commandFiles` and `eventFiles` items to a Promise. To make sure that the async function was actually completed before you called `console.log(this)` you need to await the Promises returned by the map function.

To await every item that is returned from the `map`, wrap the call in `Promise.all`:

```js
const commandFiles: string[] = await globPromise(`${__dirname}/../Commands/**/*.ts`)
await Promise.all(
    commandFiles.map(async (filePath: string) => {
        ...
    })
);

const eventfiles: string[] = await globPromise(`${__dirname}/../Events/**/*.ts`)
await Promise.all(
    eventfiles.map(async (filePath: string) => {
        ...
    })
);

console.log(this) // collections should be populated at this point
                  // because you awaited the `map` results
```

Leaving 'dangling' Promises can very often lead to some unexpected errors.

Comment: Yes this was exactly the issue, I had forgotten to handle the promises from within the map. I guess it just threw me off how it was working for the first collection and not the second.